# logging in the terminal as well as in a log message with a specific function in bash

Tags: bash, logging

I have this script

```
# Use the first argument as the path
PATH_INPUT="$1"


# To put the logfile in the run folder
LOGFILE="$PATH_INPUT/logfile.log"


logmessage(){
    # Print a message to stderr, with date + time stamp
    message="$1"
    >&2 echo -e "$( date )\t$message"
}

logmessage "-------------- Analysis starts ------------"


# Print the PATH_INPUT at the beginning of the log file
logmessage "------------ ${PATH_INPUT} --------------"
```

I want the messages in the terminal as well as saved in LOGFILE. How can I do this? I have been traying to modify my logmessage function but I cannot make it

Comment: Why not simply add the line ```echo -e "$(date)\t$message" >> $LOGFILE``` to ```logmessages()```?

Comment: Do you mean, replace that line by >&2 echo -e "$( date )\t$message"??

Comment: No, I mean adding, as in adding an element to a set.

Comment: Did you check _man tee_?

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are different ways.

Just echo twice:

```
logmessage(){
    # Print a message to stderr, with date + time stamp
    message="$1"
    >&2 echo -e "$( date )\t$message"
    echo "$( date )\t$message" >> $LOGFILE
}
```

Use `tee`:

```
logmessage(){
    # Print a message to stderr, with date + time stamp
    message="$1"
    echo -e "$( date )\t$message" | tee -a $LOGFILE 1>&2
}
```